# Msgbox if values in multiple ranges are empty

Tags: excel, vba

The below code (when there is data in column F) creates a folder, hyperlinks it and makes a Word document from Excel data, and a msgbox appears when done - `"Licence(s) and/ or folder(s) created, please delete text from column F."`.

When there is no data in column F none of this occurs and the msbox displays `"No licence(s) to create - please enter text in column F for the appropriate licence(s) you wish to create."`. I would like to get it so that it appears when this is blank as well as the corresponding cell in column N, but no matter what I try I just can't quite get it to work.

It should only show `"Licence(s) and/ or folder(s) created, please delete text from column F."` when there is text in column N and F.

```
Sub CreateLicenceFull()

Dim objWord
Dim objDoc
Dim objRange
Dim dirName As String
        On Error Resume Next
Dim Foldername As String

   r = Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
    For i = 5 To r
        With Cells(i, 5)

         If .Value = "Mobile Plant" And Cells(i, 6) <> "" And Cells(i,14) <>"" Then
            ActiveSheet.Hyperlinks.Add Anchor:=Cells(i, 4), Address:="\\Wbcphfil01.wbc.lan\dts\Groups\Operational_Services\opserv_group\Enforcement\NRSWA\Licences\Mobile Plant\Applications 2019-20\" & Cells(i, 4) & " (" & Cells(i, 12) & ")", TextToDisplay:=.Value
         dirName = Cells(4, i).Values
         MkDir ("\\Wbcphfil01.wbc.lan\dts\Groups\Operational_Services\opserv_group\Enforcement\NRSWA\Licences\Mobile Plant\Applications 2019-20\" & Cells(i, 4) & " (" & Cells(i, 12) & ")")
         Call Shell("explorer.exe" & " " & "\\Wbcphfil01.wbc.lan\dts\Groups\Operational_Services\opserv_group\Enforcement\NRSWA\Licences\Mobile Plant\Applications 2019-20\" & Cells(i, 4) & " (" & Cells(i, 12) & ")", vbNormalFocus)

        Set objWord = CreateObject("Word.Application")
        objWord.Visible = True
        Set objDoc = objWord.Documents.Add(Template:="\\Wbcphfil01.wbc.lan\dts\Groups\Operational_Services\opserv_group\Enforcement\NRSWA\Licences\Mobile Plant\Mobile Plant Licence.docx", NewTemplate:=False, DocumentType:=0)

    Set objRange = objDoc.Bookmarks("LicenceNo").Range
    objRange.InsertAfter Cells(i, 4)

    Set objRange = objDoc.Bookmarks("Date").Range
    objRange.InsertAfter Cells(i, 29)

    Set objRange = objDoc.Bookmarks("Company").Range
    objRange.InsertAfter Cells(i, 7)

    Set objRange = objDoc.Bookmarks("Address").Range
    objRange.InsertAfter Cells(i, 8)

    Set objRange = objDoc.Bookmarks("Location").Range
    objRange.InsertAfter Cells(i, 13)

    Set objRange = objDoc.Bookmarks("Location2").Range
    objRange.InsertAfter Cells(i, 12)

    Set objRange = objDoc.Bookmarks("From").Range
    objRange.InsertAfter Cells(i, 18)

    Set objRange = objDoc.Bookmarks("To").Range
    objRange.InsertAfter Cells(i, 19)

    Set objRange = objDoc.Bookmarks("Date2").Range
    objRange.InsertAfter Cells(i, 29)

    Set objRange = objDoc.Bookmarks("Name").Range
    objRange.InsertAfter Cells(i, 53)

    objWord.Visible = True
    objDoc.SaveAs ("\\Wbcphfil01.wbc.lan\dts\Groups\Operational_Services\opserv_group\Enforcement\NRSWA\Licences\Mobile Plant\Applications 2019-20\" & Cells(i, 4) & " (" & Cells(i, 12) & ")\" & Cells(i, 4) & " (" & Cells(i, 12) & ")")


MsgBox Cells(i, 4) & " - Licence(s) and/ or folder(s) created, please delete text from column F."
        End If

        If .Value = "Mobile Plant" And Cells(i, 6) <> "" And Cells(i, 14) = "" Then
        MsgBox "No licence(s) to create - please enter the application date in column N for the appropriate licence(s) you wish to create."

        End If
End With

next i

If WorksheetFunction.CountA(Range("F5:F1000")) = 0 Then
        MsgBox "No licence(s) to create - please enter text in column F for the appropriate licence(s) you wish to create."

    End If

    End Sub
```

Comment: Try changing the If condition line to `If WorksheetFunction.CountA(Range("F5:F1000")) = 0 And WorksheetFunction.CountA(Range("N5:N1000")) = 0 Then
`

Comment: I've tried that, but it still shows the wrong message - it only says the `Licences created etc` msgbox even if both cells are blank, or one cell is blank

Comment: And both the columns are empty ?

Comment: Column N will mostly contain data but it needs to check and display the msgbox for the conditions on the same row in the range

Comment: Your Msgbox is checking the complete range of `5:1000` not the individual Rows.

Comment: Would that not create a Msgbox for each row?

Comment: No.. That's like a Msgbox for Complete Data Once. Do you need for every row ? wouldn't that be messy if you have 1000 rows ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- I think you should move the below code inside loop between the lines `End With` & `Next i`
  if you want to get a msgbox at every row.
- It will be very messy though to get a Msgbox at each row. Means 1000 Msgbox Pop ups if you have 1000 rows of Data.

---

```
If Len(Range("F" & i)) = 0 And Len(Range("N" & i)) = 0 Then
    MsgBox "No licence(s) to create - please enter text in column F for the appropriate licence(s) you wish to create."
Else
    MsgBox "Licence(s) and/ or folder(s) created, please delete text from column F."
End If
```

Comment: That's similar to how I ended up approaching it, it only comes up with a Msgbox when it has the necessary now - updated code in original post.